# How do I send a state-only object containing another state-only object to a Web API controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, serialization, asp.net-web-api, datatables

I am trying to send a simple object (AjaxSubmission) from a form to a Web API controller used to edit tables.

AjaxSubmission always has the same fields. One field, "data" refers to another simple object with accessors for the specific table (Employees or Vendors examples below).

```
public class AjaxSubmission
{
    public string action { get; set; }
    public string table { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    // ...

    //// The following may be any other custom class
    public Employees data { get; set; } // Could be Vendors or whatever
}

// Stored in AjaxSubmission (or so I hope) 
public class Employees
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public float salary { get; set; }
    public long id { get; set; }
}

// Stored in AjaxSubmission 
public class Vendors
{
    public string dba { get; set; }
    public int accountNum { get; set; }
    public int zipcode { get; set; }
}
```

My controller gets the data like so:

```
public EditorServerResponse Put(AjaxSubmission ajaxSubmission = null) {
    // Handle the data
}
```

- When I make "data" an Object or Dynamic, it shows up as an empty object. I can't "as" it to Employees or Vendors because it doesn't store anything.
- I suspect this is a limitation of the serializer. MVC4 uses JSON.NET for JSON, but the data is sent as "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8".
- I cannot easily change the way data is sent because that is how the Datatables editor plug-in does its business. I think it's a reasonable way to send data and a reasonable problem for .NET to be able to handle.
- I can get the data I need if I make a distinct class for each data type that AjaxSubmission might contain, but each would be a duplicate other than one line of code. That horribly violates the DRY principle.

My question is: How can I send AjaxSubmission without Repeating Myself? Is .NET capable of such a thing?

Edit:
Fiddler says the data looks like:

```
action  edit
table   
id  row_4
data[amu]   49
data[chemicalFormula]   BF2
data[commonName]    Boron difluoride
data[status]    Y
data[notes]
```

The raw data is:
    action=edit&table=&id=row_4&data%5Bamu%5D=49&data%5BchemicalFormula%5D=BF2&data%5BcommonName%5D=Boron+difluoride&data%5Bstatus%5D=Y&data%5Bnotes%5D=

(This is different from my simplified examples but similar)

Comment: If your POST request is coming as **application/x-www-form-urlencoded**, the `FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter` should successfully  bind the action parameter. Can u inspect the message body coming in with fiddler?

Comment: @tugberk: Sure, I've added the results to the question.